# Is SABR model more used as an interpolation method or is used to risk manage option positions in practice?

Tags: options, sabr

One can risk manage option positions via sabr model (managing risks w.r.t. the sabr params), or just use sabr as an interpolation method to get black vols and risk manage option positions using black greeks. What would be the pros and cons?

Comment: I am not an expert on this but I read this post recently on SABR, quite helpful (but it's more basic). https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7121496906924449792?updateEntityUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_feedUpdate%3A%28V2%2Curn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A7121496906924449792%29